# attempt to index nil with 'Character' Error Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

Hello i am trying to get the position of the HumanoidRootPart but it says attempt to index nil with 'Character' also the FollowPlrbox has the players name.(This not a local script)
Script:

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local fwbox = script.Parent.Parent.FollowPlrbox.Text
    local player = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(fwbox)
    local plrpart = player.Character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
    local plrposx = plrpart.Position.X
    print(plrposx)
end)
```

Error:
attempt to index nil with 'Character'

Answer (score 1):

Your error is telling you that `player` doesn't exist. This could mean that whatever you have typed for the player's name is misspelled, incorrect capitalization, or there's simply no player with that name.

Anyways, you need to account for the fact that the player might not exist before trying to access properties on it. Also, since you are searching the Workspace, you are not looking for a Player, you are looking for that player's character model.

So to fix your issue, you simply need to add safety checks.

```lua
script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    local fwbox = script.Parent.Parent.FollowPlrbox.Text
    local character = game.Workspace:FindFirstChild(fwbox)
    if character then
        local rootPart = character:FindFirstChild("HumanoidRootPart")
        if rootPart then
            local rootPartPosX = rootPart.Position
            print(rootPartPosX)
        end
    end
end)
```

The reason we add `if character then` and `if rootPart then` is because it's possible that the `FindFirstChild()` function won't find anything. So we say, only do the rest of this code if character exists.